# Change html fields placeholder on select in WP

Tags: html, wordpress, forms

I want to change my field placeholder when other way of sending is chosen, email or phone. My section looks like this rn, https://cq32719-wordpress-t11rb.tw1.ru/.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aWbp.png)

I got this from chatgpt, and it works on just html file, but won't on Wordpress:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Contact Form</title>
    <style>
        label {
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="myForm">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
        
        <label for="contactSelector">Contact Method:</label>
        <select id="contactSelector" name="contactMethod" onchange="updatePlaceholder()">
            <option value="phone">Phone</option>
            <option value="email">Email</option>
        </select>
        
        <label for="contactInfo">Field 2:</label>
        <input type="text" id="contactInfo" name="contactInfo" placeholder="+7 999 999-99-99" required>
        
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

<script>    
    function updatePlaceholder() {
        const selector = document.getElementById("contactSelector");
        const field2 = document.getElementById("contactInfo");

        if (selector.value === "email") {
            field2.placeholder = "example@gmail.com";
        } else if (selector.value === "phone") {
            field2.placeholder = "+7 (000) 000-00-00";
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It's probably bcs I don't have onchange in my select field, but I can't add this to wp's field